# Access object indentifier, like var_dump?

Tags: php, debugging, object

var_dump function showing a object indentifier for each object output, for example:

```
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable();
var_dump($now);
```

The output is:

```
object(DateTimeImmutable)#412 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-04-29 21:31:55.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Is this 412 is unique in group of all current objects ?

How to access this number more efficently ?

Comment: This is just an identifier used internally by PHP. It's not likely to be unique.

Comment: `How to access this number more efficently` - what for? what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to save all current objects before closing the program and than load them again. I want to use this identifier to know that i am not saving the same object twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that internal identifier is something you have to worry about. If you want to save variables and restoring them later, you can use `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

EDIT: may be `spl_object_hash()` could be what you need?

http://php.net/spl_object_hash

Comment: yes, that is what i'm doing. But my object are big, that is why looking for other ways

Comment: check the SPL function that I added in the answer!